# Creating graph linked to dynamic range

Tags: excel, vba

I have created 2 dynamic ranges on a worksheet that is linked to a graph on another worksheet in the workbook. I have my X-values as one named range, and the Y-values are the other named range. However, the graph won't display any data now. Is there a reason the graph is not recognizing the named ranges? I have one range named `Enter_Time` written as

`=Process_Checks!$D$6:INDEX(Process_Checks!$6:$6,COUNTA(Process_Checks!$6:$6)+1)`

and the other range named as `Sample1` written as

```
=Process_Checks!$D$7:INDEX(Process_Checks!$7:$7,COUNTA(Process_Checks!$7:$7))
```

When I go to set up my graph, I've simply typed `={"Enter_Time"}` in the X-value line and

`={"Sample1"}` into the Y-value line, but nothing displays on the graph.

Thanks in advance, I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your named ranges are valid and contain data, you need to enter the workbook name before with dynamic ranges e.g.

```
=TestBook.xlsb!Enter_Time
```

Comment: It always is that simple...worked perfectly. Thank you!